# How do I display a matrix in a method?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, matrix, formatting

For some reason, I can't get my method to display a previously mentioned array. The only issue is in my first line. The error code is: "illegal start of expression". What am I doing wrong?

```
    public static void display(int matrix[][]) {
        for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < matrix[row].length; col++) {
                System.out.print(matrix[row][col] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This method is probably inside another method..

Comment: On which line does the error occur? Did you forget to close the method before this one?

Comment: Please post the whole class, we need to see more of your code to give you a precise answer.

Comment: On a side note, is this method outputting a satisfactory enough format of your matrix? I see that you're using a single space `" "` as a separator which will inevitably give a ragged output if some matrix entries have a minus sign or different numbers of digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your method has to be inside the class, but outside any other method.
if this method is within the main method, then your code will look something like this:

```
public class name
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         //code
         yourmethod(parameter); //*somewhere in your code*
    }

    public static void yourmethod(parameters p)
    {
         //code
    }
}
```

if it's within a regular class with no main method

```
public class name
{
    public name()
    {
        //code
    }

    public void yourmethod(parameters p)
    {
        //code
    }

    //other methods
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is not in that method, surely you missed a `}` before

Comment: Actually it turns out I just forgot to move it out of the main method. My mistake. Thank you, though.